# ValueError: [E024] Could not find an optimal move to supervise the parser. while training custom NER using Spacy v3.x

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3, custom-training

while training my custom NER model using spacy v3.x,

```
!python -m spacy train /content/drive/MyDrive/Interview_Buddy/config.cfg --output ./output
```

it is throwing me above error.

" ValueError("[E024] Could not find an optimal move to supervise the parser.
Usually, this means that the model can't be updated in a way that's valid and
satisfies the correct annotations specified in the GoldParse. "

for converting my json data to new Spacy v3.x recommended format, i used this code

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

nlp = spacy.blank("en") # load a new spacy model
db = DocBin()

for text, annot in tqdm(training_data): # data in previous format
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot["entities"]: # add character indexes
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        if span is None:
            print("Skipping entity")
        else:
            ents.append(span)

    doc.ents = ents # label the text with the ents
    db.add(doc)
db.to_disk("./training_data.spacy")
```

what should i have to do? Thanks in advance

config file

```
[paths]
train = null
dev = null
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = null

[system]
gpu_allocator = null
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["tok2vec","ner"]
batch_size = 1000
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}

[components]

[components.ner]
factory = "ner"
moves = null
update_with_oracle_cut_size = 100

[components.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v2"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 64
maxout_pieces = 2
use_upper = true
nO = null

[components.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
upstream = "*"

[components.tok2vec]
factory = "tok2vec"

[components.tok2vec.model]
@architectures = "spacy.Tok2Vec.v2"

[components.tok2vec.model.embed]
@architectures = "spacy.MultiHashEmbed.v1"
width = ${components.tok2vec.model.encode.width}
attrs = ["NORM","PREFIX","SUFFIX","SHAPE"]
rows = [5000,2500,2500,2500]
include_static_vectors = false

[components.tok2vec.model.encode]
@architectures = "spacy.MaxoutWindowEncoder.v2"
width = 96
depth = 4
window_size = 1
maxout_pieces = 3

[corpora]

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 2000
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[training]
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"
seed = ${system.seed}
gpu_allocator = ${system.gpu_allocator}
dropout = 0.1
accumulate_gradient = 1
patience = 1600
max_epochs = 0
max_steps = 20000
eval_frequency = 200
frozen_components = []
before_to_disk = null

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_words.v1"
discard_oversize = false
tolerance = 0.2
get_length = null

[training.batcher.size]
@schedules = "compounding.v1"
start = 100
stop = 1000
compound = 1.001
t = 0.0

[training.logger]
@loggers = "spacy.ConsoleLogger.v1"
progress_bar = false

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
L2_is_weight_decay = true
L2 = 0.01
grad_clip = 1.0
use_averages = false
eps = 0.00000001
learn_rate = 0.001

[training.score_weights]
ents_per_type = null
ents_f = 1.0
ents_p = 0.0
ents_r = 0.0

[pretraining]

[initialize]
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = ${paths.init_tok2vec}
vocab_data = null
lookups = null
before_init = null
after_init = null

[initialize.components]

[initialize.tokenizer]
```

Comment: Can you share your config?

Comment: @polm23 i have just shared my config file above

Comment: What is the output of `spacy debug data`?